# MySQL query to retrieve data from 5 tables shows error

Tags: mysql

I make a mysql query to retrieve data from 5 tables and tables are :

```
inv_supplier, 
inv_receive, 
inv_receivedetail, 
inv_material, 
inv_materialcategory
```

And my query is

```
SELECT inv_receive.mrr_no,
       inv_receive.mrr_date,
       inv_receivedetail.material_id,
       inv_material.material_description,
       inv_receivedetail.receive_qty,
       inv_receivedetail.unit_price,
       inv_receivedetail.total_receive,
       inv_receive.supplier_id,
       inv_supplier.supplier_company,
       inv_receivedetail.sl_no,
       inv_receive.receive_type,
       inv_materialcategory.category_id,
       inv_material.qty_unit,
       inv_receive.purchase_id,
       inv_receive.receive_acct_id,
       inv_receive.remarks,
       inv_receive.receive_total,
       inv_receive.jv_no 
FROM inv_materialcategory 
INNER JOIN inv_receivedetail 
INNER JOIN inv_material ON inv_receivedetail.material_id = inv_material.material_id 
                        ON inv_materialcategory.material_sub_id = inv_material.material_sub_id 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN inv_supplier 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN inv_receive ON inv_supplier.supplier_id = inv_receive.supplier_id 
                        ON inv_receivedetail.mrr_no = inv_receive.mrr_no;
```

but it shows an error like that :

```
Error
Static analysis:

6 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected token. (near "=" at position 672)
Unexpected token. (near "inv_material" at position 674)
Unexpected token. (near "." at position 686)
Unexpected token. (near "material_sub_id" at position 687)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "ON" at position 816)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "ON" at position 816)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT inv_receive.mrr_no, inv_receive.mrr_date, inv_receivedetail.material_id, inv_material.material_description, inv_receivedetail.receive_qty, inv_receivedetail.unit_price,inv_receivedetail.total_receive, inv_receive.supplier_id, inv_supplier.supplier_company, inv_receivedetail.sl_no, inv_receive.receive_type, inv_materialcategory.category_id, inv_material.qty_unit, inv_receive.purchase_id, inv_receive.receive_acct_id, inv_receive.remarks, inv_receive.receive_total, inv_receive.jv_no FROM inv_materialcategory INNER JOIN inv_receivedetail INNER JOIN inv_material ON inv_receivedetail.material_id = inv_material.material_id ON inv_materialcategory.material_sub_id = inv_material.material_sub_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN inv_supplier RIGHT OUTER JOIN inv_receive ON inv_supplier.supplier_id = inv_receive.supplier_id ON inv_receivedetail.mrr_no = inv_receive.mrr_no

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON  inv_materialcategory.material_sub_id = inv_material.material_sub_id RIGHT OU' at line 1
```

could anybody please help me to identify the errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the way you have the joins written; try this:

```
SELECT inv_receive.mrr_no,
       inv_receive.mrr_date,
       inv_receivedetail.material_id,
       inv_material.material_description,
       inv_receivedetail.receive_qty,
       inv_receivedetail.unit_price,
       inv_receivedetail.total_receive,
       inv_receive.supplier_id,
       inv_supplier.supplier_company,
       inv_receivedetail.sl_no,
       inv_receive.receive_type,
       inv_materialcategory.category_id,
       inv_material.qty_unit,
       inv_receive.purchase_id,
       inv_receive.receive_acct_id,
       inv_receive.remarks,
       inv_receive.receive_total,
       inv_receive.jv_no 
FROM inv_materialcategory 
 
INNER JOIN inv_material ON inv_material.material_sub_id = inv_materialcategory.material_sub_id   
INNER JOIN inv_receivedetail ON inv_receivedetail.material_id = inv_material.material_id 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN inv_receive  ON inv_receive.mrr_no = inv_receivedetail.mrr_no                      
RIGHT OUTER JOIN inv_supplier ON inv_supplier.supplier_id = inv_receive.supplier_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all fields in select which you are trying to map in JOIN operation.

Like inv_material.material_id this field is not added in 'select'. Check others and add them.

and, add 'AND' condition instead of adding ON

INNER JOIN inv_material ON inv_receivedetail.material_id = inv_material.material_id
AND inv_materialcategory.material_sub_id = inv_material.material_sub_id

Comment: Don't look at messages printed by the parser - it is NOT MySQL parser. Its messages are too far from the reality.

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN {rows source} ON {join condition}` does not allow to insert something else into.

Look at the fragment

```
INNER JOIN inv_receivedetail 
INNER JOIN inv_material ON inv_receivedetail.material_id = inv_material.material_id 
                        ON inv_materialcategory.material_sub_id = inv_material.material_sub_id
```

Investigate its second `ON` clause. What clause is posessed immediately before it? Another, first in this fragment, `ON` clause. This is an error.

Simply reorder tables in FROM clause and set correct `ON` conditions order - all tables mentioned in the condition must be already listed above.

```
FROM inv_materialcategory 
INNER JOIN inv_material ON inv_materialcategory.material_sub_id = inv_material.material_sub_id
INNER JOIN inv_receivedetail ON inv_receivedetail.material_id = inv_material.material_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN inv_supplier ON inv_supplier.supplier_id = inv_receive.supplier_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN inv_receive ON inv_receivedetail.mrr_no = inv_receive.mrr_no
```